# Convert netCDF to NumPy array with xarray: unable to allocate

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a DataArray which is too large to convert to a NumPy array:

```py
da = xr.open_dataset('tprate.grib', engine='cfgrib').tprate
da.values
```

I got:

`Unable to allocate 8.56 TiB for an array with shape (28, 7008, 185, 180, 360) and data type float32`

If I `isel` part of the DataArray by the first two dimensions, it is able to convert:

`ncep_da.isel(number=0, time=0).values`

But if I `isel` the last two dimensions, the memory used remained unchanged:

`ncep_da.isel(latitude=0, longitude=0).values`

I still got:

`Unable to allocate 8.56 TiB for an array with shape (28, 7008, 185, 180, 360) and data type float32`

I guess this is because the second sub array is not stored sequentially on the disk as the rightmost dimension is the inner loop of the data.

Is there any way to extract the second sub array and convert it to NumPy array efficiently?

Comment: So it's running out of RAM when you do `da.values`? Why isn't it running out of memory for `da`? Was this created on a machine with 8TB RAM? ---- Please try doing `open_dataset(cache=False)` and tell me if that prevents loading.

Comment: @xjcl Thank you. I guess it is because I used `open_dataset()` instead of `load_dataset()`. `open_dataset()` does not load the whole data array into memory. If I use `load_dataset()`, it will run out of memory at the beginning. BTW, it seems that `open_dataset(cache=False)` did not change anything.

Comment: That sucks. Why don't you ask the person who created the dataset, or someone else working with it?

Comment: I download it from [CDS](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/) myself. This system will combine all data you chose into one file. I guess if this problem can not be solved, I need to re-download this data separately.

Comment: @Weixin You might need to use `dask` to achieve this. This will be enabled by adding kwarg `chunks` to `xr.open_dataset()`.  You might need to give explicit chunk sizes for your dimensions.